# How do I keep All Trails on top of an Apple Watch?

Tags: applications, apple-watch, watchos

I use the All Trails App on my watch in order to provide quickly accessible navigation information when I am cycling.  The last time I did so, I also started a cycling workout task via the built-in Fitness App.  What I quickly found out was that the watched seemed to prioritize displaying the fitness information and not the All Trails map.  So I'd have to lift the watch up, re-select All Trails to see where I was meant to be going, and then when I put my arm down again, and re-lifted it - the fitness data was displayed.

How do I tell my watch that I want the All Trails app to display all the time, and only want to see the fitness app when manually select it?

This is with an Apple Watch 8, watchOS 9.5.1

Answer (score 2):

Normally, one can configure the behaviour of the app in Watch.app General → Return to Clock to set Apple Watch to only return to the clock after 1 hour of the app being inactive.

However, an active fitness session overrides this behaviour.

Therefore it's up to the app to implement ‘extended runtime sessions’.

> An app running on Apple Watch normally transitions to the background and becomes suspended when the user lowers their wrist. However, your app can use both background sessions and extended runtime sessions to continue running after the user stops interacting with it.

> Extended runtime sessions […] give your app several different session types to choose from. […] Some keep your app active and running as the frontmost app instead.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions

Contact the developer of All Trails to be able to [`start()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextendedruntimesession/3131067-start) a [WKExtendedRuntimeSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextendedruntimesession) from the app.

Comment: All Trails behaves OK when the fitness app is not running.  So you are saying that Apple's policy is that the fitness app overrides other apps? And I was hoping for a solution for my 7AM start tomorrow morning .. lol

Comment: Actually I think I see the solution.  In General → Return to Clock → Workout, I could set "Return to App" to "Off".  Having 2 apps both trying to duke it out could be the issue.

Comment: Interesting. I use all trails for hiking and want the opposite. The watch does much better job calculating my distance so I’m happy the coin flip chose workouts over All Trails when I was testing both at the same time. It will be nice if people could choose one over the other, though. I’ll follow this closely in case I have a tip that could help you @PeterM